# simple crawler in php to echo links

Tags: php

I wanted to make a simple crawler in php that would let me get the links in a web page, echo their url, and crawl to other pages to do the same under a certain domain. Would using cURL be necessary here? Also..how would one specify depth of the crawler.

I have this so far :

```
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node ) {
    echo $dom->saveXml($node), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: If the only question is about "to use or not to use CURL" - then the answer is "Yes, use it"

Comment: well I also want to know how to do this...Im fairly new to cURL...and I've been looking around quite a bit

Comment: I think I would add that you may run into timeout limits with PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Snoopy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy/), a simple wrapper around curl. Below is some sample code

```
/*
You need the snoopy.class.php from 
http://snoopy.sourceforge.net/
*/
 
include("snoopy.class.php");
 
$snoopy = new Snoopy;
 
// need an proxy?:
//$snoopy->proxy_host = "my.proxy.host";
//$snoopy->proxy_port = "8080";
 
// set browser and referer:
$snoopy->agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)";
$snoopy->referer = "http://www.jonasjohn.de/";
 
// set some cookies:
$snoopy->cookies["SessionID"] = '238472834723489';
$snoopy->cookies["favoriteColor"] = "blue";
 
// set an raw-header:
$snoopy->rawheaders["Pragma"] = "no-cache";
 
// set some internal variables:
$snoopy->maxredirs = 2;
$snoopy->offsiteok = false;
$snoopy->expandlinks = false;
 
// set username and password (optional)
//$snoopy->user = "joe";
//$snoopy->pass = "bloe";
 
// fetch the text of the website www.google.com:
if($snoopy->fetchtext("http://www.google.com")){ 
    // other methods: fetch, fetchform, fetchlinks, submittext and submitlinks
 
    // response code:
    print "response code: ".$snoopy->response_code."<br/>\n";
 
    // print the headers:
 
    print "<b>Headers:</b><br/>";
    while(list($key,$val) = each($snoopy->headers)){
        print $key.": ".$val."<br/>\n";
    }
 
    print "<br/>\n";
 
    // print the texts of the website:
    print "<pre>".htmlspecialchars($snoopy->results)."</pre>\n";
 
}
else {
    print "Snoopy: error while fetching document: ".$snoopy->error."\n";
}
```

You need to use "fetchlinks" to get the links.